# How to fetch all data from dynamic table using Function & Stored Procedure in the PostgreSQL database? table name passed in parameter

Tags: postgresql

I am tryign to fetch data from dynamic table using Function but getting error: "SQL Error [42704]: ERROR: type "schemaName.p_dynamictablename" does not exist".

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schemaName."GetAllDataFromDynamicTable"(IN P_DynamicTableName text, IN id integer)
    RETURNS SETOF schemaName."P_DynamicTableName" 
AS $$
BEGIN
  return query
    SELECT * FROM schemaName."P_DynamicTableName" WHERE "Id" = id;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I am tryign to fetch data from dynamic table using Stored Procudure but getting error: "SQL Error [42704]: ERROR: type "ml.tableName" does not exist"

Note: able to fetch data from table. ex: select * from schemaName."TableName";

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schemaName."GetAllDataFromDynamicTable"(tableName character varying)
  RETURNS SETOF schemaName."tableName" 
as $$
BEGIN
  return query 
    select * from schemaName."tableName";
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Please clean up your tags. c#, .net and sql-server have nothing to do with your question.

Comment: remove quotes from table name while querying it

Comment: Read [Dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN).

Comment: On closer reading I realized this `RETURNS SETOF schemaName."P_DynamicTableName" ` is not going to be able to be made dynamic. So you can't do this. What is the purpose of the function vs just running the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by @Adrian, dynamic sql could be a solution :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetAllDataFromDynamicTable(IN P_DynamicTableName text, IN id integer)
    RETURNS SETOF record
AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY
    EXECUTE FORMAT('SELECT * FROM %I WHERE id = %s', P_DynamicTableName, id) ;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But calling this function will lead to an error until you can explicitly define the output columns of the function. This is possible only in the case where all the tables to be queried dynamically have the same columns definition.

There is a workaround which consists in converting the output record into a json object :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NewGetAllDataFromDynamicTable(IN P_DynamicTableName text, IN id integer)
    RETURNS SETOF jsonb
AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY
    EXECUTE FORMAT('SELECT to_jsonb(t.*) FROM %I AS t WHERE t.id = %s', P_DynamicTableName, id) ;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then you can call the function in different ways :

`SELECT t.* FROM NewGetAllDataFromDynamicTable ('test', 1) AS t` will return a json object

`SELECT (jsonb_populate_record(NULL :: "test", t.*)).* FROM NewGetAllDataFromDynamicTable ('test', 1) AS t` will return the columns of the table `test`

see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yhADbvbI)

Comment: Awesome! your solutions are working fine for me.

Comment: How can I pass the table name with schema? ex: SELECT (jsonb_populate_record(NULL :: ml."Test", t.*)).* FROM NewGetAllDataFromDynamicTable (ml."Test", 13) AS t; getting error in this query SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "ml"

Comment: what is `ml` a your query ?

Comment: 'ml' is a schema name. like PostgreSQL default schema name is 'public'.

Comment: what happens when you replace `FROM NewGetAllDataFromDynamicTable (ml."Test", 13) AS t` by `FROM NewGetAllDataFromDynamicTable ('ml.Test', 13) AS t` ?

Comment: SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "'ml.Test'" => SELECT (jsonb_populate_record(NULL :: 'ml.Test', t.*)).* FROM NewGetAllDataFromDynamicTable ('ml.Test', 13) AS t;

Comment: the problem comes from `%I` in the dynamic sql statement which adds double quotes. If you want to pass `shema_name.table_name` in the input parameter `P_DynamicTableName ` you must replace `%I` by `%s`. Or you can also add a new input parameter `P_DynamicShemaName` and update the dynamic statement : `EXECUTE FORMAT('SELECT to_jsonb(t.*) FROM %I.%I AS t WHERE t.id = %s', P_DynamicSchemaName, P_DynamicTableName, id) ;`

Comment: Thank you so much. I passed schema_name & table_name as 2 separate parameters and working fine.